# htaccess url rewrite and PHP $_GET['id'] issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url from

> message.php?id=372186

To

> message/372186

Here's my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^message/([^/.]+)/?$ /message.php?pg=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

I can load up example.com/test/message/372186 fine but when I try to fetch the page id it returns nothing.

If I use message.php?id=372186 the PHP works fine.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
// output for message.php?id=372186 is: 372186
// output for message/372186 is: 
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^message/([^/.]+)/?$ /message.php?pg=$1 [L]`

See the line there where you say ?pg=$1 ?

You are trying $_GET['id'] when you should be using $_GET['pg']

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm stupid. I changed it to message.php?id=$1 though still not working.

Comment: try doing a var_dump($_GET) and see what your $_GET variable contains to debug

Comment: also try using this regex for testing, it accepts all: ^message/(.*)/$

Comment: I am not 100% sure if it matters or not, but if won't work with/without trailing slash you might have to create a second rule

Comment: Tried those two, the var_dump comes up with array(0) { }, it's not able to get any data

Comment: check your apache httpd.conf your url rewrites might be off